# How to store the hidden layer as a variable to visualize it

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.in_dim = 28 * 28
    self.out_dim = 10

    self.fc1 =nn.Linear(self.in_dim,512)

    self.fc2=nn.Linear(512, 256)
    self.fc3 =nn.Linear(256, 128)
    self.fc4 =nn.Linear(128, 64)
    self.fc5 =nn.Linear(64, self.out_dim)

    self.relu = nn.ReLU()

  def forward(self, x):


      a1 = self.relu(self.fc1(x.view(-1,self.in_dim)))    

      a2 = self.relu(self.fc2(a1))
      a3 = self.relu(self.fc3(a2))
      a4 = self.relu(self.fc4(a3))
      logit = self.fc5(a4)

      return logit
```

For example, in the code above, I want to store the a1 and (self.fc1(x.view(-1, self.in_dim))) parts as separate variables for visualization and make it NumPy. How are you?

I got a hint to save with np.save(filepath, a1.numpy()) , but that's wrong, so I ask again.

Comment: What is wrong with `np.save`?

Answer (score 0):

- You can add `a1`, `a2` ... to the return statement, and use them later on in your code
- To cast them in `numpy.ndarray`, you could use something like `a1.detach().cpu().numpy()`
- As for visualization, it does depend of the shape of the tensor // numpy array you obtain.